# PowerApps Meeting Capture Template UserProfileV2 Error

Tags: powerapps

Using one of the existing PowerApps templates, I created the Meeting Capture app. When I launch the app, select a meeting, then enter the meeting I get the following error message citing "Office365Users.UserProfilev2 failed" (see screenshot). 
[image]

When I return to PowerApps, this error is identified as coming from HomePopUpsScreen. 
[image]

Below is the O365 plan my company provides.
[image]

Since this was created from a MS PowerApps template, I wasn't expecting to incur issues. Any recommendations?

Comment: I have already tried removing and adding back all the connections and the issue remains.